# Ошибка при получении данных json

Tags: php, ajax

Загружаю контент при скролле, в денвере все работает а на сервере нет, помогите найти ошибку. Я не понимаю в чем проблема.

Все файлы в utf-8, в .htaccess utf-8. Вообще все выводит без ошибок, ошибка только при подгрузке.

Преобразую массив в json строку `echo json_encode($articles);`

Преобразую обратно в массив `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Код обработчика:

```
<?php

include 'resources/php/db.php';
mysqli_query ($db, 'set character_set_results = "utf8"');
// C какой статьи будет осуществляться вывод
$startFrom = $_POST['startFrom'];

$city = $_POST["cityurl"];

$categor = $_POST["categorurl"];
// Получаем 10 статей, начиная с последней отображенной
 $cities = array(
    'Брестская область' => array(
       'Брест', 'Барановичи', 'Береза', 'Ганцевичи',
       'Дрогичин' ,'Жабинка' ,'Иваново', 'Ивацевичи',
       'Каменец' ,'Кобрин', 'Лунинец', 'Ляховичи',
       'Малорита' ,'Пинск', 'Пружаны', 'Столин',
       'Брестская область'),
    'Витебская область' => array(
       'Витебск','Бешенковичи', 'Браслав', 'Верхнедвинск',
       'Глубокое', 'Городок', 'Докшицы', 'Дубровно',
       'Лепель', 'Лиозно', 'Миоры', 'Орша', 'Полоцк',
       'Поставы', 'Россоны', 'Сенно', 'Толочин', 'Ушачи',
       'Чашники', 'Шарковщина', 'Шумилино', 'Витебская область'),
    'Гомельская область' => array(
       'Гомель', 'Брагин', 'Буда-Кошелево', 'Ветка',
       'Добруш', 'Ельск', 'Житковичи', 'Жлобин',
       'Калинковичи', 'Корма', 'Лельчицы', 'Лоев',
       'Мозырь', 'Наровля', 'Октябрьский', 'Петриков',
       'Речица', 'Рогачев', 'Светлогорск', 'Хойники',
       'Чечерск', 'Гомельская область'),
    'Гродненская область' => array(
       'Гродно', 'Берестовица', 'Волковыск', 'Вороново',
       'Дятлово', 'Зельва', 'Ивье', 'Кореличи',
       'Лида', 'Мосты', 'Новогрудок', 'Островец',
       'Ошмяны', 'Свислочь', 'Слоним', 'Сморгонь',
       'Щучин', 'Гродненская область'),
    'Минская область' => array(
       'Минск', 'Березино', 'Борисов', 'Вилейка',
       'Воложин', 'Дзержинск', 'Жодино', 'Клецк',
       'Копыль', 'Крупки', 'Логойск', 'Любань',
       'Марьина Горка', 'Молодечно', 'Мядель', 
       'Несвиж', 'Слуцк', 'Смолевичи', 'Солигорск', 
       'Старые Дороги', 'Столбцы', 'Узда',
       'Червень', 'Минская область'),
    'Могилёвская область' => array(
       'Могилев', 'Белыничи', 'Бобруйск', 'Быхов', 
       'Глуск', 'Горки', 'Дрибин', 'Кировск', 'Климовичи',
       'Кличев', 'Костюковичи', 'Краснополье', 'Кричев',
       'Круглое', 'Мстиславль', 'Осиповичи', 'Славгород', 
       'Хотимск', 'Чаусы', 'Чериков', 'Шклов', 'Могилёвская область')
  );

  $categors = array(
    'Детский мир' => array(
       'Детский мир', 'Детская одежда', 'Детская обувь', 
       'Детские коляски', 'Детские автокресла', 'Детская мебель',
       'Игрушки', 'Детский транспорт', 'Товары для кормления', 'Товары для школьников',
       'Прочие детские товары'),
    'Недвижимость' => array(
       'Недвижимость','Аренда квартир','Аренда комнат',
       'Аренда домов','Аренда земли','Аренда гаражей / Стоянок',
       'Ищу компаньона','Продажа квартир','Продажа комнат',
       'Продажа домов', 'Продажа земли','Продажа гаражей / Стоянок',
       'Аренда помещений','Продажа помещений','Прочая недвижимость',
       'Обмен недвижимости'),
    'Транспорт' => array(
      'Транспорт','Легковые автомобили','Мото','Автобусы',
      'Спецтехника','Грузовые автомобили','Сельхозтехника',
      'Водный транспорт','Воздушный транспорт','Запчасти / Аксессуары',
      'Прицепы','Другой транспорт','Авто / Мото услуги'),
    'Работа' => array(
      'Работа','Розничная торговля / Продажи','Транспорт / Логистика',
      'Строительство','Бары / Рестораны','Юриспруденция и Бухгалтерия',
      'Охрана / Безопасность','Домашний персонал','Красота / Фитнес / Спорт',
      'Туризм / Отдых / Развлечения','Образование','Культура / Искусство',
      'Медицина / Фармация','ИТ / Телеком / Компьютеры','Недвижимость',
      'Маркетинг / Реклама / Дизайн','Производство / Энергетика',
      'Cекретариат / АХО','Частичная занятость','Начало карьеры / Студенты',
      'Сервис и Быт','Другие сферы занятий'),
    'Животные' => array(
     'Животные','Собаки','Кошки','Аквариумистика',
     'Птицы','Грызуны','Рептилии','Сельхоз животные',
     'Животные даром','Зоотовары','Вязка','Бюро находок',
     'Другие животные'),
    'Дом и Сад' => array(
       'Дом и Сад','Канцтовары / Расходные материалы',
       'Мебель','Предметы интерьера','Строительство / Ремонт',
       'Инструменты','Комнатные Растения','Посуда / Кухонная утварь',
       'Садовый Инвентарь','Сад / Огород','Хозяйственный инвентарь / Бытовая химия',
       'Прочие товары для дома'),
     'Электроника' => array(
        'Электроника','Телефоны','Компьютеры',
        'Фото / Видео','Тв / Видеотехника','Аудиотехника',
        'Игры и Игровые приставки','Техника для дома',
        'Техника для кухни','Климатическое оборудование','Индивидуальный уход',
        'Аксессуары и комплектующие','Прочая электроника'),
      'Услуги / Бизнес' => array(
            'Услуги / Бизнес','Строительство / Ремонт / Уборка',
            'Финансовые услуги / Партнерство','Перевозки / Аренда транспорта',
            'Реклама / Полиграфия / Маркетинг / Интернет','Няни / Сиделки',
            'Сырьё / материалы','Красота / Здоровье','Оборудование','Образование / Спорт',
            'Услуги для животных','Продажа бизнеса','Развлечение / Искусство / Фото / Видео',
            'Туризм / Иммиграция','Услуги переводчиков / Набор текста','Авто / Мото услуги',
            'Обслуживание, Ремонт техники','Сетевой маркетинг','Юридические услуги',
            'Прокат товаров','Прочие услуги'),
        'Мода и Cтиль' => array(
            'Мода и Cтиль','Одежда/обувь','Для свадьбы',
            'Мода разное','Наручные часы','Аксессуары',
            'Подарки','Красота / Здоровье'),
        'Хобби, Отдых и Спорт' => array(
            'Хобби, Отдых и Спорт','Антиквариат / Коллекции',
            'Музыкальные инструменты','Другое','Спорт / Отдых',
            'Книги / Журналы','CD / DVD / Пластинки / Кассеты',
            'Билеты','Поиск попутчиков','Поиск групп / Музыкантов')
  );

if(isset($_POST['cityurl'])) {
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь') {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT {$startFrom},12";
    } elseif(array_key_exists($city, $cities)) {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE city IN ('" . implode("','", $cities[$city]) . "')
                  ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
                  LIMIT {$startFrom},12";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE city = '$city'
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT {$startFrom},12";
    }
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}

if(isset($_POST['categorurl'])) {
    if($categor == 'Все категории') {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT {$startFrom},12";
    } elseif(array_key_exists($categor, $categors)) {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE categor IN ('" . implode("','", $categors[$categor]) . "')
                  ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
                  LIMIT {$startFrom},12";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE categor = '$categor'
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT {$startFrom},12";
    }
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}

if( isset($_POST['cityurl']) and isset($_POST['categorurl']) ) {
    $where = array();
    $where=array("1=1");
    if($categor && $categor != 'Все категории') {
    if(array_key_exists($categor, $categors)) {
    $where[]="categor IN ('" . implode("','", $categors[$categor]) . "')";
    } else
    {
    $where[]="categor='$categor'";
    }
    }
    if($city && $city != 'Вся Беларусь') {
    if(array_key_exists($city, $cities)) {
    $where[]="city IN ('" . implode("','", $cities[$city]) . "')";
    } else
    {
    $where[]="city='$city'";
    }
    }
    $query = "SELECT *
                FROM `articles`
            WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where) . "
            ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
            LIMIT {$startFrom},12";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}



if( !isset($_POST['cityurl']) and !isset($_POST['categorurl']) ) {
    $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles`  ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT {$startFrom},12");
}
// Формируем массив со статьями
$articles = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $articles[] = $row;
}

// Превращаем массив статей в json-строку для передачи через Ajax-запрос
echo json_encode($articles);
```

Код вызова:

```
var inProgress = false;
/* С какой статьи надо делать выборку из базы при ajax-запросе */ 
var startFrom = 12;

    $(window).scroll(function() {


        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() -166 && !inProgress) {
        $.ajax({            
            /* адрес файла-обработчика запроса */
            url: 'scroll.php',
            /* метод отправки данных */
            method: 'POST',
            /* данные, которые мы передаем в файл-обработчик */
            data: {"startFrom" : startFrom},
            /* что нужно сделать до отправки запрса */
            beforeSend: function() {
            /* меняем значение флага на true, т.е. запрос сейчас в процессе выполнения */
            inProgress = true;}
            /* что нужно сделать по факту выполнения запроса */            
            }).done(function(data){

            /* Преобразуем результат, пришедший от обработчика - преобразуем json-строку обратно в массив */ 
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            /* Если массив не пуст (т.е. статьи там есть) */
            if (data.length > 0) {

            /* Делаем проход по каждому результату, оказвашемуся в массиве,
            где в index попадает индекс текущего элемента массива, а в data - сама статья */                 
            $.each(data, function(index, data){

            /* Отбираем по идентификатору блок со статьями и дозаполняем его новыми данными */    
            $("#articles").append("<div class='article'><div class='article_title'>" + data.title + "</div><div class='article_img'><img src=" + data.img1 + "></div><a href='#' class='article_more'>Подробнее</a></div>");
            });

            /* По факту окончания запроса снова меняем значение флага на false */
            inProgress = false;
            // Увеличиваем на 10 порядковый номер статьи, с которой надо начинать выборку из базы
            startFrom += 12;
            }});   
        }
    });
```

Добавил условия и все заработало, не знаю в чем была проблема раз в денвере все работало

```
if(isset($_POST["cityurl"]))
    $city = $_POST["cityurl"];
if(isset($_POST["categorurl"]))
    $categor = $_POST["categorurl"];
```

Comment: Если не сложно, приведите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Обратите внимание, в денвере регистронезависимая файловая система, на сервере - нет. Посмотрите черех средства разработчика, уходит ли запрос, куда уходит, что приходит в ответ.

Comment: @cheops http://prntscr.com/bdriqj, на 219 parseJSON

Comment: @ilyaplot Все файлы в нижнем регистре, вот ошибка http://prntscr.com/bdriqj ,  на 219 parseJSON, наверно ошибка при получении

Comment: Очевидно, что вместо json сервер отвечает html. Добавьте перед data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); console.log(data); И посмотрите результат в консоли. Рекомендую использовать не .done, а success, error, dataType в $.ajax

Comment: @ilyaplot Вот что выходит http://prntscr.com/bds8p8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$city = $_POST["cityurl"]; 
$categor = $_POST["categorurl"];
```

Я не вижу что бы в запросе передавались POST параметры cityurl и categorurl.
Думаю, что вместе с Json в ответе приходят notice

Comment: Дело в том что у меня там много условий, посмотрите в код обработчика, там есть условие что если эти переменные пусты то получаем все объекты



`function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
var cityurl = getUrlVars()["city"];
var categorurl = getUrlVars()["categor"];
var cityurl = urldecode(cityurl) ;
var categorurl = urldecode(categorurl) ;`

Comment: Я не вижу в .ajax этого. В php получим notice. Покажите console.log(data) перед parseJSON

Comment: Вот что выходит http://prntscr.com/bds8p8

Comment: Как я и думал. $city = !empty($_POST["cityurl"]) ? $_POST["cityurl"] : null; 
$categor = !empty($_POST["categorurl"]) ? $_POST["categorurl"] : null;

Comment: Скрипт пытается получить данные из массива $_POST, но т.к. данные не были переданы, то и в массиве $_POST нет соответствующих ключей. Об этом говорит скрипт с помощью NOTICE. Когда на входе у parseJson встречается начало того самого notice, он выкидывает ошибку и не пытается далее прочесть json.

Comment: @Как не переданы если в ошибке на скриншоте есть текст который передаётся? А именно там английские символы передаются нормально но на русских кракозябра

Comment: @идентикон Внимательно перечитайте мои комментарии. Я имею в виду не передачу от сервера клиенту, а наоборот. Используйте isset или empty перед присвоением переменной. Кстати, в коде много мест для sql injection.

Comment: Спасибо Ваммммм

Comment: Даже если там пусто то в денвере почему тогда все работает?
Не может там пусто быть так как если бы там было NULL я бы ничего вообще не получал. Потому как срабатывала бы сортировка и следовательно не выводило ничего

Comment: в денвере не было notice. error_reporting отличается или display_errors off

Comment: Я же говорю, если бы там было null, notice или что угодно то в консоли я бы в ответе не видел вообще ничего, потому как у меня выводятся все записи если эти переменные пусты и сортирует по их содержимому если они не пусты, так что если они бы были null или notice то консоль была бы пуста так как в базе совпадений нет и нечего передавать, разве что ошибку. А в консоли были краказябры на месте русских символов, и нормальный текст который был на латинице.